# Vimeo video unmuted button on desktop

Tags: desktop, squarespace, vimeo-player

I have trouble when setting embed data for Vimeo on Squarespace.

I have set the iframe code with autoplay = 1 and muted=1 and it works fine on mobile. When I play the video on mobile, it will show the button tap to unmute the video.

However, on the desktop, the video only shows the button to play/pause and has no button to unmute it.

Is there anyone getting into this trouble and do you have any solution for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this might be helpful for you

```js
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);
player.on('play', function() {
    console.log('video played');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Iframe video Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="vidz" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/401649410?h=11d74aa27c&amp;portrait=0" width="450" height="253" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```